# Use List class in Java

Tags: java, arrays, list, game-engine

I want to create game tic-tac-toe. I use the `List` class to determine a winner. I use `List` in several methods. How do I create this class in main method so that I can use `List` other method later?

I have attached my code so that you understand my question.

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> playerPositions = new ArrayList<>(); //создадим список для определения победителя
        List<Integer> CPUpositions = new ArrayList<>();

        //создать двумерный массив для отрисовки игры
        char[][] gameBoard = new char[][] {
            { ' ', '|', ' ', '|', ' '},
            { '-', '+', '-', '+', '-'},
            { ' ', '|', ' ', '|', ' '},
            { '-', '+', '-', '+', '-'},
            { ' ', '|', ' ', '|', ' '}
        };
        // printGameBoard(gameBoard);
    }

    public static String checkWinner() {
        List toprow = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
        List midrow = Arrays.asList(4, 5, 6);
        List botrow = Arrays.asList(7, 8, 9);
        List col1 = Arrays.asList(1, 4, 7);
        List col2 = Arrays.asList(2, 5, 8);
        List col3 = Arrays.asList(3, 6, 9);
        List cross1 = Arrays.asList(1, 5, 9);
        List cross2 = Arrays.asList(3, 5, 7);
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: if you want to use a List in multiple methods you should declare it as static member of the Main class

Comment: **Warning:** you are using a *raw type*: `List` takes a *type argument*, but you have provided none within your `checkWinner()` method. You should replace all occurrences of `List` by `List<Integer>`.

Answer (score 0):

You create your ArrayList within the main method. Therefore you cannot access those variables outside of the main method.
You should declare them as private class variables like this:

```
public class Main {

    List<Integer> playerPositions = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> CPUpositions = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Do sth with playerPositions and CPUpositions
    }
```

Comment: Note that, in order to use those two fields, OP must create an instance of `Main`.

Comment: @MCEmperor thats true if he wants to use the fields in other classes. The question just mentioned to use the fields in several methods. I assume he meant methods within the same class.

Answer (score 0):

Create a static List of List, which has topRow, botRow etc. in it

```
List<List> winningList;
```

and check if playerPositions contains any of the List in winningList or CPUpositions contains any of the list part of winningList.

Whichever has the list has won.

Answer (score 0):

There's multiple ways to go about this:

a) create playerPositions and CPUpositions as static  class variables - basically what user dcnis said, except you'll need to add the "static" keyword to be able to use them without instanciating a "Main" object:

```
public class Main {

static List<Integer> playerPositions = new ArrayList<>();
static List<Integer> CPUpositions = new ArrayList<>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Do sth with playerPositions and CPUpositions
}
```

Alternatively, you can pass the lists down to your functions as an argument:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    List<Integer> playerPositions = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> CPUPositions = new ArrayList<>();
    checkWinner(playerPositions, CPUPositions);
}
public static void checkWinner(List<Integer> playerPositions, List<Integer> CPUPositions){
    //do cool stuff with those lists
}
```